# How to change composer global vendor directory in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, composer-php, global, vendor

Something is wrong with my composer local installation.

I'm under ubuntu 22, my global vendor directory path is pointing to a project directory and not to a SO global directory, such as /home/username/.composer/vendor.

Take a look to this output

```
composer config --global -l
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in phar:///home/gik/.local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php:879
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in phar:///home/gik/.local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php:884
[repositories.packagist.org.type] composer
[repositories.packagist.org.url] https://repo.packagist.org
[process-timeout] 300
[use-include-path] false
[use-parent-dir] prompt
[preferred-install] dist
[notify-on-install] true
[github-protocols] [https, ssh]
[gitlab-protocol] 
[vendor-dir] vendor (/home/username/workspaces/myproject/vendor)
[bin-dir] {$vendor-dir}/bin (/home/username/workspaces/myproject/vendor/bin)
[cache-dir] /home/username/.cache/composer
[data-dir] /home/username/.local/share/composer
[cache-files-dir] {$cache-dir}/files (/home/username/.cache/composer/files)
[cache-repo-dir] {$cache-dir}/repo (/home/username/.cache/composer/repo)
[cache-vcs-dir] {$cache-dir}/vcs (/home/username/.cache/composer/vcs)
[cache-ttl] 15552000
[cache-files-ttl] 15552000
[cache-files-maxsize] 300MiB (314572800)
[cache-read-only] false
[bin-compat] auto
[discard-changes] false
[autoloader-suffix] 
[sort-packages] false
[optimize-autoloader] false
[classmap-authoritative] false
[apcu-autoloader] false
[prepend-autoloader] true
[github-domains] [github.com]
[bitbucket-expose-hostname] true
[disable-tls] false
[secure-http] true
[cafile] 
[capath] 
[github-expose-hostname] true
[gitlab-domains] [gitlab.com]
[store-auths] prompt
[archive-format] tar
[archive-dir] .
[htaccess-protect] true
[use-github-api] true
[lock] true
[platform-check] php-onl
[home] /home/username/.config/composer
```

The question are: How can i change this directory path (vendor-dir and bin-dir) ? Why I am experiencing this problem? What I did wrong?

I tried to check if there is a "set" command that allows me to update this global config variables vendor-dir and bin-dir with no results.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it using different searching keywords

As suggested here https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/4450

You can update whatever variable in your configuration (either global or local) using the following command:

```
composer config variable_name variable_value
```

hope this helps.